# Rebuilding checkbox indicators as in quick favourites

Tags: python

In the Viewport Overlays there is an option to show / hide all bones.
I added this toggle to my quick favourites.

[image: Quick Favourites - Show Bones]

I would like to re-build the same behaviour inside my own 'quick favourite like' menu.

How can I do something like that on my own menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeling qualified to answer this by myself:

Inside the draw() method of the menu class, the self.layout.prop() method can to be used to access a property and automatically draw the desired checkbox:

```
class MyMenu(bpy.types.Menu):

    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_my_menu" 
    bl_label = "My Menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(view3d_overlay, "show_bones", text="Toggle Bones")
```